# Are --save-dev modules included when electron packaging? If so, how can I exclude them all?

Tags: javascript, electron

There are many dependencies and devDependencies in my project and I would like to package my project folder with `electron-packager` in asar mode.

While doing so, does it automatically exclude devDependencies?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev dependencies are not included by default in electron package made with `electron-packager`.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager

> If you put them [the node modules] in the devDependencies section of package.json, by default none of the modules related to those dependencies will be copied in the app bundles. (This behavior can be turned off with the --no-prune flag.) In addition, folders like .git and node_modules/.bin will be ignored by default.